# For each $A \in M_n(\mathbb R)$ there exists $B \in M_n(\mathbb R)$ such that $A=B^t-2B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Assume that $A \in M_n(\mathbb R)$ is an arbitrary $n \times n$ matrix  such that its elements come from $\mathbb R$.
Prove that there exists $B \in M_n(\mathbb R)$ such that $A=B^t-2B$

My try :

I defined a linear-map $T:M_n(\mathbb R) \to M_n(\mathbb R)$ such that $T(B)=B^t-2B$.  Now i wan't to show that this linear-map is one-to-one. After i showed this, i can say that $T$ is surjective too. So, we're done.

The thing that i'm stuck on, is how to prove that $T(B)$ is one-to-one.

Note : Please don't use entirely different ways to solve the problem. Help me to complete my way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: with $B^t$ you mean $B$ transposed, right?

Comment: @JimmyR. yes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For symmetric matrices $A$ this is immediate with the choice $B=-A$. For skew symmetric matrices, again with $B=-\frac13A$.  For non-symmetric matrix $A$ write $$A=\frac12(A+A^t)+\frac12(A-A^t)$$
where $A+A^t$ is symmetric and $A-A^t$ skew-symmetric, so there exist $B_1$ and $B_2$ such that $$A=\frac12(B_1^t-2B_1)+\frac12(B_2^t-B_2)=\frac12\left(B^t_1+B_2^t-2(B_1+B_2)\right)=\frac12(B^t-2B)$$ with $B=B_1+B_2$.